# Using dynamic dates in a SQL pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the below code that works well but I don't want to continue typing in the dates daily.

My dates will always be the last 7 days (including today) - meaning that the table will be purged daily and the new data pull in daily.

```
select *
from
(
 select EMP_ID, EMP_SHORT_NAME, SEG_CODE, 
NOM_DATE
from sick_codes_Test$
) src
pivot
(
max(seg_code)
for nom_date in ([2018-07-14], [2018-07-15],[2018-07-16],[2018-07-17],[2018-07-18],
           [2018-07-19], [2018-07-20])
) piv
```

So for "nom_date in" how can I make those dates the dates that will just be in the table?

I tried following along with the following link

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

But wasn't able to make it work

From following the above URL I came up with this code

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N',' + QUOTENAME(NOM_DATE)
FROM   sick_codes_Test$  

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
 SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_SHORT_NAME, SEG_CODE
 from sick_codes_Test$
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  max(seg_code) FOR nom_date IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ',  [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging around I think I found a possible solution but after running the below I seeing the EMP_ID being duplicated.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(NOM_DATE)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NOM_DATE FROM sick_codes_Test$ ) AS NOM_DATE
 order by NOM_DATE ASC
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_SHORT_NAME, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM sick_codes_Test$
PIVOT(MAX(SEG_CODE) 
      FOR NOM_DATE IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

After more modifications I finally found a solution that worked

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(NOM_DATE)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NOM_DATE FROM sick_codes_Test$ ) AS NOM_DATE
order by NOM_DATE ASC
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_SHORT_NAME, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID,
EMP_SHORT_NAME,
SEG_CODE,
NOM_DATE
FROM sick_codes_Test$
)t
PIVOT(MAX(SEG_CODE) 
      FOR NOM_DATE IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```